# How to apply max function to a list of columns(given list of column names) in Data.Table without using apply()?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to optimize existing code written using dataframe. I found out that data.table performs faster than it without using apply functions. Here is the link I followed:https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-12-11/Solve-common-R-problems-efficiently-with-data.table.html

Old Code:

```
apply(DF0[,select_cols[grep("_MD",end_char)]],1,max,na.rm=TRUE)
```

`DF0` --> dataframe
`select_cols[grep("_MD",end_char)]` --> list of column names on which max function applied.

What above code does: it finds maximum among values of different columns for every row.(finding maximum horizontally)

I want to use Datatable in this way.

```
dt[, .(sum(x), .N), grp]
```

as per above link and mentioned in "R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate" section.

It is fastest way of using.

Please help me out with writing in Data.table format. 
I am stuck at how to use list of column names in datatable.

Comment: With `data.table`, you may need something like `setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD,  max, na.rm = TRUE), grp, .SDcols = grep("_MD", names(df1))]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun for the answer. could you describe a little bit? I believe .SDcols=select_cols[grep("_MD",end_char)]] as it is list of column names.

Comment: You can pass numeric index or column names, if you neeed column names, use `value = TRUE`in `grep`.  Ok, I see you are extracting from another object.  Then it should be `select_cols`

Comment: If you're trying to find a `max` across each row, I think you might want something like `pmax` - `dat[,do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols=c("var1","var2","var3")]` for instance.

Comment: Okay. I tried running. It gives error like:"Object  grp not found". Also in my case .SDcols is simply-   select_cols[grep("_MD",end_char)]]  as this list contains specific columns names not all names of  DF. @akrun

Comment: @jkat I meant to use that `select_cols[grep("_MD",end_char)]]`  Also, if it is the row wise max, you may use thelatemail's suggestion

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. It worked. but another apply statements with DataFrame Syntax gives an error like "Error during wrapup: dim(X) must have a positive length".   I think it is because I used setDT(DF). it does not make copy but it changes DF to DT. Could you please help in that?

Comment: If I use this with Datatable then is it faster than the old syntax with apply and dataframe? I tried Microbenchmark but datatable is very slower than the previous one @thelatemail